# problem when inserting figure

Tags: graphics

> I have been trying to insert an image to my LaTeX test book so I can further experiment with it, but the only thing which I see is the file path's name. I have tried some proposed solutions on both stackoverflow and other websites, but none worked -- what am I missing?

**What I have tried:**

1. Including the image as follows:

```latex
\begin{figure}[h] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Plot}
    \caption{$J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ as regards to $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$}
    \label{fig:Fig1}
\end{figure}
```

2. Instead of Plot in the previouds code, use `Plot.png`
3. Removing the `\graphicspath{ {Images/} }` line

**Notes:**

1. The image (Plot.png) is in the folder Image.
2. I use overleaf, however, the overleaf's sample from the official website worked as a charm.

**Full code:**

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[utf8]{amsmath, amssymb}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }

\title{LINEAR REGRESSION IN DETAIL}
\author{Alexandros Voliotis \thanks{University of Thessaly}}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
Test title of my first \textbf{ \LaTeX} document!


Italics: \textit{test}

Underline: \underline{test}


\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Introduction}

In the gradient descent algorithm we are trying to minimize the value of $J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ for some $\theta_0, \theta_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is quite tough to achieve in a few steps, however it is not entirely impossible. In order to make $J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ equal to $0$, we must first set the step variable accordingly, and measure every time the output. This process should, and will, create a table with two columns as shown below:
\begin{itemize}
  \item 1\textsuperscript{st} column -- The values for the step variable.
  \item 2\textsuperscript{nd} column -- The values for the total tries variable.

\end{itemize}


A better visualization of the function $J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ is as follows:

\begin{figure}[h] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Plot}
    \caption{$J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ as regards to $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$}
    \label{fig:Fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast answer: include `\usepackage{float}` and use `[H]` instead of `[h]`

Explained answer:
There's the errors or recommendations that I have founded:

1. Use lowercase letters for labels, path of folders, and others that usually refers object. For example use `\label{tbl:its an example}` instead of `\label{tbl:Its An Example}`. Why? because usually we forgot uppercase letters.
2. Include `\usepackage{float}` to use `[H]` or `[h]` in `\begin{figure}[H]` on your documents.
3. Use `\usepackage{amsmath}` `\usepackage{amssymb}` instead of your code if you have no errors with this.

I fixed some common errors in the code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float} % For placement of figures, tables, and other objects
\graphicspath{{imagesfolder/}} % use lowercase to avoid errors for typing

\title{LINEAR REGRESSION IN DETAIL}
\author{Alexandros Voliotis \thanks{University of Thessaly}}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
Test title of my first \textbf{ \LaTeX} document!


Italics: \textit{test}

Underline: \underline{test}


\chapter{Mathematics}

\section{Introduction}

In the gradient descent algorithm we are trying to minimize the value of $J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ for some $\theta_0, \theta_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is quite tough to achieve in a few steps, however it is not entirely impossible. In order to make $J(\theta_0, \theta_1)$ equal to $0$, we must first set the step variable accordingly, and measure every time the output. This process should, and will, create a table with two columns as shown below:
\begin{itemize}
  \item 1\textsuperscript{st} column -- The values for the step variable.
  \item 2\textsuperscript{nd} column -- The values for the total tries variable.

\end{itemize}


A better visualization of the function $ J(\theta_0, \theta_1) $ is as follows (\ref{fig:figure 1}):

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image.png}
    \caption{$ J(\theta_0, \theta_1) $ as regards to $\ theta_0 $ and $ \theta_1 $}
    \label{fig:figure 1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input! I managed to solve this problem by actually switching the compile mode from "fast" to "normal" -- even your code wouldn't run without this change. However, it would be great if you could expand a bit more on why I would need to use the float package, and if I could utilise `\floatplacement` for more efficiency or better graphing (I guess?).

Comment: Ohh I see, it's necessary because LaTeX recognizes "tables" and "figures" as floats objects [Full documentation here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)